# ajaxForm plugin + rails ujs feature disable with on submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript, ajaxform

I want to use [ajaxForm plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and rails ujs feature 'disable with' on submit button.

I found one simple way as I think:

in erb:

```
<%= form_for @some_object do |f| %>
  # some object inputs
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", 'data-disable-with' => 'Loading...' %>
<% end %>
```

in js:

```
$('form').ajaxForm(
  dataType: "script",
  complete: function() {
    $('form').trigger('ajax:complete.rails')
  }
)
```

without this JS we will have disabled submit button 'Loading...'

Maybe someone knows a more right way, eh?

Comment: Hey, how about: <%= form_for @some_object, remote: true do |f| %> ... This doesn't require any plugin. More here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

Comment: Thank you. I know about this way but I want to use some callback from ajaxForm. And I had some problems with fileupload using remote: true before.